# Lipschitzianity of cone functions

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

> Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty open set and $C$ be a cone
>   function with vertex $x_o$ and slope $b$. Then
>   $L(C, D)=|b|$. Moreover, if $D$ is bounded and
>   $x_o\notin D$, then $L(C,\partial D)=|b|$.

**Some notations.** For *cone function with vertex $x_o$* we mean a function $C$ of the form $C(x)=a+b|x-x_o|$ where $a$ and $b$ are the *height* and the *slope* respectively. Moreover, the half-line 
$$
t\longmapsto x_o+t(x-x_o),\quad x\neq x_o
$$
is called the *ray* of $C$ through $x$.

Now, proving that if $D$ contains two distinct points on the same ray of a cone function $C$ with vertex $x_o$ and slope $b$, it holds $L(C, D)=|b|$, is simple. Indeed if $y\neq w$ are two points on the same ray of $C$, we have, for a certain $x^*$, $y=x_o+\alpha(x^*-x_o)$ and $w=x_o+\beta(x^*-x_o)$ with $\alpha,\beta\geq0$, $\alpha\neq\beta$. Then
$$
\frac{|C(y)-C(w)|}{|y-w|}=\ldots=|b|.
$$

But, how can I prove the statements before? Some helps?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z\in D$, let $\nu := \frac{z-x_0}{\|z-x_0\|}$ and define
$$
t^- := \inf\{t<0:\ z+s\nu\in D\ \forall s\in [t,0]\},
\quad
t^+ := \sup\{t>0:\ z+s\nu\in D\ \forall s\in [0,t]\}.
$$
(The two sets are nonempty since, being $D$ open, $z$ is an interior point of $D$.)
Then the points $y^\pm := z + t^\pm \nu$ belong to $\partial D$ and to the same ray.

Comment: Is it possible that there is another way to see this? For example, I think that since $x_o\notin D$, $C\in C^0(\overline{D})$ and hence $L(C, \overline{D})=L(C, D)=|b|$. In particular $L(C, \partial D)=|b|$.

Comment: I do not see how the condition $x_0\not\in D$ enters in your deduction. You always have the equality $L(C, \overline{D}) = L(C,D)$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake. The equality $L(C, \overline{D})=L(C, D)$ always holds. Thanks.